# AngularJS Conditional data display problem

Tags: angularjs

`I have a problem on how to display a conditional value.
Here is an example of the data whose elements I would like to display:

```
"dataList" : [
    {
       "title" : "Title 1",
       "part" : "Part 1",
       "num" : "7",
       "code" : "yyAD_ikd@4&",
       "rfa" : null, 
    },
    {
       "title" : "Title 2",
       "part" : "Part 2",
       "num" : "2",
       "code" : null,
       "rfa" : "m9*shuf#sd",
    },
    {
       "title" : "Title 3",
       "part" : "Part 3",
       "num" : "2",
       "code" : null,
       "rfa" : "Z%usjd&&alp",
    }
]
```

I need to loop to display the data in a table containing 3 columns (Title, Part and Info).
The problem arises on the Info column which must contain the "code" if "num"=7 and the "rfa" if "num"=2.
Knowing that if the code is present then the rfa is null, and vice versa.

I was able to do something like this but it doesn't work as expected (the title and part are well displayed but not the info) :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-body-center" ng-hide="true">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Part</th>
        <th>Info</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="res  in dataList">
        <td>{{res.title}}</td>
        <td>{{res.part}}</td>
        <td ng-show="res.code">{{res.code}}</td>
        <td ng-show="res.rfa">{{res.rfa}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The correct expected result in my example case should be the following :

| Title | Part | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title 1 | Part 1 | yyAD_ikd@4& |
| Title 2 | Part 2 | m9*shuf#sd |
| Title 3 | Part 3 | Z%usjd&&alp |

Comment: Why not simply do: 
```<td>{{ res.code ?? res.rfa }}</td>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) something like

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-body-center" >
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Part</th>
        <th>Info</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="res  in dataList">
        <td>{{res.title}}</td>
        <td>{{res.part}}</td>
        <td>{{res.code== null ? res.rfa : res.code}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Or

```
<td>{{res.code || res.rfa}}</td>
```